# Preventing discord bot from crashing (mysql)

Tags: mysql, discord.js

I have a discord bot and I'm working on a command that shows info about a character(by providing the character name) from a mysql database. It works fine but if I provide a name that doesn't exist in the database like `!characterinfo asdasfefcdce`, the bot crashes. So my question is `How do I prevent it from crashing if I provide a wrong name?`. Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const {stripIndents} = require("common-tags");
const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, connection3) => {

    if (message.content == '!characterinfo') {
        return message.reply('provide a character name!');
    }

    const name = args[0];

    connection3.query('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name = ?', [name], function(err, results, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle('**Character Information**')
    .addField('Nickname:', results[0].name)
    .addField('Level:', results[0].level)
    .setFooter(`test`)

    .setTimestamp();

     message.channel.send(embed);
  });

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "characterinfo",
}
```

If you need me to provide you more info, let me know.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot crashes at the moment because in this line

```
if (err) throw err;
```

you throw an error and don't handle it later, the simplest way to change this is to replace throw by console.log or console.error

```
if (err) console.error(err);
```

Or you could keep the throw and wrap the code with a try/catch.

```
try {
    connection3.query('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name = ?', [name], function (err, results, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle('**Character Information**')
            .addField('Nickname:', results[0].name)
            .addField('Level:', results[0].level)
            .setFooter(`test`)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send(embed);
    });
} catch(err) {
    // Handle the error ...
    console.log(err)
}
```

EDIT: So the error is actually coming from the results array not having any entries when the query doesn't find a result, so this solution should work.

You should check to see if there's a "results" before doing anything else.

```
try {
    connection3.query('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name = ?', [name], function (err, results, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!results[0]) return;

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle('**Character Information**')
            .addField('Nickname:', results[0].name)
            .addField('Level:', results[0].level)
            .setFooter(`test`)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send(embed);
    });
} catch(err) {
    // Handle the error ...
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: I tried both methods but it still gives the same error if I type a name that's not in the database
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Check if there's a result before creating the embed, I'll update the answer with the code.

Comment: I mean... it works perfectly fine when I use a name that's in the database but when I use one that's not in the DB, I get that error.

Comment: I added the new solution to the answer, try that out.

Comment: Still the same :c

Comment: I didn't read the error properly, change if (!results) return; to if (!results[0]) return;

Comment: Wow, that one worked!! Thanks man! Really appreciate your time and help!